# Pausar y Reproducir audio con un botones usando MediaPlayer Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, mediaplayer

Estoy haciendo una aplicación reproductor de audio en Android Studio. En la aplicación se pueden seleccionar tres canciones mediante un spinner. Tambien tengo tres botones uno de play, otro de pausa y otro de stop. Funciona todo correctamente excepto cuando finaliza la canción que ya no puedo seleccionar otra. He intentado usar `mp.realease()` para liberar el audio pero siempre me rompe.
Os paso el codigo por si me podeis echar una mano. Muchisimas gracias!!

```
public class ReproductorAudio extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Spinner sp_audio;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    int pause;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio);
        sp_audio = findViewById(R.id.sp_audio);
    }

    public void playAudio (View Vista){
       int select = sp_audio.getSelectedItemPosition();
       if (mp == null){
            if(select == 0) {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.jinjer);
            } else if (select == 1){
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.inception);
            } else if (select == 2){
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.manishboy);
            }
            mp.start();
        } else if(!mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.seekTo(pause);
            mp.start();
        }
    }

    public void pauseAudio (View Vista){
        if (mp != null){
            mp.pause();
            pause = mp.getCurrentPosition();
        }

    }

    public  void stopAudio (View vista){
        mp.stop();
        mp = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Que se muestra en el LogCat cuando se "rompe", recuerda que es importante agregar a tus preguntas el mensaje de error para que la comunidad te ayude de mejor forma.

Comment: No me aparece nada porque con este código la aplicación no rompe. Sólo que no carga la canción que selecciono. No da error. Solo se carga una vez la cancion y si esta termina ya no puedo cambiarla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se encuentra en la lógica de tu código, si existe una instancia de `MediaPlayer` ya no podrá reproducir otro audio, primero obtén el audio y posteriormente instancia el `MediaPlayer` con el audio seleccionado.

Muy importante usar [OnPreparedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setOnPreparedListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener)):

> [OnPreparedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setOnPreparedListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener)) Registra un callback que indica la fuente de
> medios esté lista para la reproducción.

al responder este callback puedes iniciar la reproducción usando .start().

```
int lastSelection = 0;
boolean mismoElemento = false;

public void playAudio (View Vista){

   int select = sp_audio.getSelectedItemPosition();

   if(lastSelection == select){
     mismoElemento = true; 
   } 

   int audio = 0;
   if(select == 0) {
        audio = R.raw.jinjer;
   } else if (select == 1){
        audio = R.raw.inception;
   } else if (select == 2){
        audio = R.raw.manishboy;
   }

   if (mp != null && !mismoElemento){
       mp.release();
       mp = null;
       mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, audio);   
   } else if(mp != null) {
       mp.seekTo(pause);       
   }else {
       mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, audio);
   }

    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {       
             mp.start(); //*Inicia reproducción.
       }
   });


   lastSelection = select; //Define el elemento seleccionado para después compararlo.

}
```

Como ejemplo puedes revisar:

[Android-MediaPlayer-play-sounds-in-ListView](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-MediaPlayer-play-sounds-in-ListView)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta. Me faltaban bastantes cosas que no llegaba a comprender. Ahora si funciona. :D
Me vino muy bien el articulo tambien.